# Does Javascript eval correctly evaluate tri-state boolean logic which includes null variables, i.e. unknowns?

Tags: javascript, eval

I know that Javascript's eval can evaluate expressions like

```
(true) && (false)
(true) || (false) 
 etc.
```

However, does the specification of eval include evaluating statements involving unknowns like

```
(true) && (null)
(true) || (null)
(null) && (null)
(null) || (null)
 etc.
```

I have tried this in code and seen that it does it, but is this expected behavior? Do the Javascript eval specifications say this?

Comment: `null` is falsy in Javascript, not "nully".

Comment: Oh and do you _need_ reminding that eval is evil?

Comment: @JanDvorak I am using eval to generate test data. Nothing evil about that.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Javascript eval correctly evaluate tri-state boolean logic?

Define "correct". Javascript defines the behavior. `Eval` in Javascript evaluates the string as a javascript code. SQL defines the behavior as well. The behavior is different in both.

In javascript, `null` acts like `false` in boolean expressions (is falsy).

`0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined` (and of course `false`) are all falsy. Objects, non-empty strings and non-zero numbers (and of course `true`) are all truthy.

`&&` returns the first falsy argument (if any) or the last argument (lazy AND) and does not evaluate the rest. `null && "anything"` is `null`. This can be used in statements like `console && console.log && console.log()`.

`||` returns the first truthy argument (if any) or the last argument (lazy OR) and does not evaluate the rest. `null || "something"` is `"something"`. This can be used in statements like `var xhr = XmlHttpRequest || ItsReplacementInOlderBrowsers`

`!null` evaluates to `true`. `if(null) ...` evaluates the `else` branch. The same applies to anything falsy.

Technically, undefined variables are `undefined`, not `null`. Both are falsy, though.

Answer (score 0):

null evaluates to false, but keep in mind that there are more details involving null (eg: the use of ===).

Please check out this page.  It covers this in more detail:
http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls:_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN

Comment: Which caveats are you referring to with comparing to null? I think you're thinking of NaN. Null evaluates just like every other item on that list except NaN.

Comment: @DennisPlucinik: Maybe caveat was a bad term.  I meant cases where === should be used.  I'll rephrase the answer.

Comment: === should always be used regardless. There is no case where == is more useful than it is confusing and error prone.

Comment: Completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not "unknown", when placed as an operand in a comparison it is simply coerced to a boolean (`false`). See the row for `null` in this ["truthy table"](http://jsfiddle.net/QjSYG/9/) for more information.

I don't believe there is any "specification" for behavior of `eval` - all it does it take a string representation of javascript and execute it as javascript in the current context. There is no reason that

```
eval('(true) && (null)');
```

would give you different results than

```
(true) && (null)
```

Also, [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Comment: `eval` executes in the current scope, not in the global scope. This answer sounds as if this wasn't the case. Note that the context in the specification refers to the `this` object.

Comment: @JanDvorak right, i was thinking of `setTimeout`, i will edit. thanks.